# Why is ac showing 0.00 on macOS under an admin account?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, posix

I'm on macOS 10.12, running an admin account, and when I run `ac` from zsh I get:

```
┌[me@My-MacBook-Pro] [/dev/ttys000] 
└[~]> ac
       total        0.00
```

Why? It's supposed to show user logged-on time, but I'm always getting 0.

Comment: @slhck Oops, I lost my own bet, it's working fine in Sierra for me.

Comment: @wmjbyatt it works for me from an admin account, but gives me zero from a non-admin account. Are you logging into an admin or non-admin account?

Comment: @slhck I'm on 10.12

Comment: @Spiff I'm on an admin account